# Can the ARM assembly code compiled by RVCT compiler run on an android device?

Tags: android, assembly, arm, adb

My Assembly code is (code.s)

```
       AREA ARMex, CODE, READONLY
       ENTRY
start
       MOV  r0, #10         
       MOV  r1, #3
       ADD  r0, r0, r1          
stop
       SWI  0x11                
       END
```

To generate object file i used "armasm -g code.s"
To generate executable i used "armlink code.o -o code"
Is this executable run on Android device?? What are the steps to be followed?
I tried using adb commands to run the executable on android, the commands are
adb push code cd/data
adb shell
cd data
chmod 777 code
./code
Output is "KILLED"
What does this mean?

Comment: It should be possible to compile with arm's toolchain then link with android's gcc but what you try looks already too crude. What's swi 0x11? It says killed probably because kernel can't load your elf properly. try to get some familiarity with ndk and produce a sensible assembly that you can play with then switch to mixing toolchains. Using strace on device should help a lot. Also see this one https://github.com/auselen/agoapf/tree/master/smallest_elf

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that ARM uses two types of instruction set: Thumb and ARM.

Some devices only support Thumb instruction set.

There are also two different types of system calls in Linux:

OABI: This is the "SWI #11" stuff.

EABI: This requires "SWI #0" and the system call number (#11) in the R7 register.

As far as I know Android uses EABI.